# Can a bowler call batsman back if he takes his wicket?

Tags: rules, cricket

If a bowler takes the wicket of a batsman, then after that can the bowling side's captain or the bowler call the batsman back on the field to play again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible, and has indeed happened (at least) once in a Test match, where the India Captain,Gundappa Viswanath, [recalled the England Wicketkeeper](http://www.espncricinfo.com/wisdenalmanack/content/story/153583.html) Bob Taylor.

> ...umpire Hanumantha Rao upheld an appeal against Taylor for a catch
>   behind the wicket, off Kapil Dev. Taylor hesitated and protested at
>   the decision. Viswanath, the Indian captain, who was fielding at first
>   slip, was as certain as the batsman that there had been no contact and
>   persuaded the umpire to rescind his verdict.

Viswanath was a successful batsman in the India side in the 1970s, but only captained two Test matches. His [cricinfo profile](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/player/35712.html) suggests that this was typical of his manner:

> He played the game in its true spirit: a century had little value to
>   him if it didn't contribute to the team cause and he disputed an
>   umpire¹s decision only once, recalling Bob Taylor in the Golden
>   Jubilee match against England in 1979-80. It cost him the Test, one of
>   only two where he led India, but to Vishy, it mattered more that the
>   game should be played fair.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a captain can withdraw an appeal should he decide to. [See Law 27 section 8](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-27-appeals/). He must have the agreement of the relevant umpire, and it must take place immediately after the fall of wicket.

Answer (score -2):

When we are consulting with cricketing history its reveal that the team captain can withdraw from the wicket.. He can overlap the umpire's decision.